# Unclear why question about thermostats remains closed

Tags: discussion

Question in question: [Powering home thermostat using standard four-wire connection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650949/powering-home-thermostat-using-standard-four-wire-connection)

This is a question about building a thermostat to work with a standard home HVAC communication protocol. It was closed (IMO, incorrectly) as

> This question does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope defined in the help center.

IMO, it is quite clearly a question that covers:

> - a specific electronics design problem

and

> - a communication scheme

and most certainly is not

> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
> - Programming software for a PC

Nonetheless, I submitted some suggested edits based on comments in the answer, to correct some factual errors that were causing confusion in the original post. Even after that, though, the only feedback from that edit and reopen request is:

> Original close reason(s) were not resolved

Which doesn't make sense to me, since the original close reason didn't apply.

I left a comment on the post itself, but unfortunately nobody responded to it explaining why. What am I missing about this question that makes it inappropriate? FWIW, this is the second question I've seen closed in the past few days that was worthy of an answer -- in neither case was the reason for closure explained.

Comment: I've reopened the question BECAUSE I agree with the argument re inappropriate close reason BUT I'd hope that the points I've addressed in comments could be addressed. MattS can easily improve the question to the point where I'd understand it. The two links that I added in comments would also allow that if I waded through them.

Comment: I don't know what the initial close reason was, but in the state the question was in when you raised this meta post, *I would have* closed it for lacking clarity. Russell explains it well. It boils down to an old point: Should a question be comprehensible only to specific "experts" or to everyone ? The latter is obviously unattainable but taking it into account *somewhat* helps with the question not getting viciously closed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen this until now.
Long experience has led me to (strongly :-) ) believe that I am better than most people at understanding technical questions which are obscurely put and / or which contain inadequate information.

I have not met systems as described in the question.
The terms are meaningless to me.
eg " ... Rc/G/W/Y, ..." seems likely to refer to the wire designations / applications, but would not allow me to start to answer the question well.
As edited the question is tailored only for a person experienced and proficient in the art.  If you can find such people to answer the question then it may succeed, BUT if it was well described it's quite possible that I could provide a useful answer.

Your (Matt S's) answer provides excellent explanatory information.
If appropriate parts of this were in the question it may be answerable by eg me.
I'm generally resistant to closing questions.
As it stands I agree with the decision made - although the reasons given is, as often, probably inappropriate. .
**NB**: Reasons for closing are very limited and often do not well reflect the close reason. In this case I'd say that "substantially lacking in detail" would be much closer.

+1 on Matt S's answer :-)

Comment: I've read all of your comments @tobalt and Russell, very much appreciated and understood. I submitted a suggested edit to the post that I think might make the question a little more accessible to the broader community. (Not sure why I'm so attached to this question... but I know I had similar confusion when I first cracked open a thermostat.) I'm pretty new around here and I appreciate the guidance you've given!

Comment: Surely it is not appropriate to close questions just because they are only answerable by experts in a particular subject area, e.g. questions about a certain ADC or communication protocol or register of a microcontroller.